# SQL query specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Need help in converting data from table into specific format in report

Can somebody advise

here is the raw data

```
Source Table data 

Year ID     Value
1YR Low     0.048
1YR High    0.13
1YR Val     0.09
3YR Low     0.058
3YR High    0.096 
3YR Val     0.077 


Output 
        Val     Range 
1 Yr    0.09    0.048 to 0.13
3 Yr    0.077   0.058 to 0.09
```

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Could you give us the definition of your source table?

Comment: does the source table have column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May need a little tidying but this is what I think you need :

```
SELECT val.year, val.value, cast(low.value as varchar(6))  
 + ' to '  + cast(high.value as varchar(6))   as range
from yourTable val 
INNER JOIN yourTable low on val.year = low.year 
INNER JOIN yourTable high ON
val.year = high.year
  where val.id='val'
AND low.id='Low'
AND high.id='High'
```